# Why is no PatternSyntaxException thrown for my invalid pattern?

Tags: java, regex, unit-testing, patternsyntaxexception

I want to test whether a regexp is valid in Java 1.8.0_241

```
public static boolean isRegExpValid(String regExp) {
    try {
        Pattern.compile(regExp);
        return true;
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here I am testing a correct regexp for a three digit number, and an incorrect regexp.

```
@Test
public void testValidRegexp() {
    assertTrue(isRegExpValid("\\d{3}"));
}

@Test
public void testInvalidRegexp() {
    assertFalse(isRegExpValid("{3}"));
}
```

Why is my second test `testInvalidRegexp` failing? `isRegExpValid("{3}")` should return false, but  returns true.

In Javascript, `{3}` correctly fails with a **Nothing to repeat** exception.
[image]

Comment: Really? `Pattern.matches("{3}", "{3}")` yields `false`.

Comment: `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("{3}"); pattern.asPredicate().test("{3}");` produces `true`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No it doesn't. To match literally `{3}`, the regex must be `"\\{3\\}"`

Comment: @VLAZ that `test` will pass for anything -- it's still not a literal match. `asPredicate` is backed by a `find`, so a pattern that matches an empty string will be found in any string passed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to successfully match the empty string:

```
jshell> Pattern.matches("{3}x", "x")
$1 ==> true
```

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) doesn't appear to define this as a valid use, but it passes where other minor syntax problems would be detected and throw `Pattern.error`.

To analyse why the implementation accepts this, you'd want to figure out where [`Pattern#closure`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#L3330) can be called from while parsing a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`{3}` is a valid regex in Java but **it will only match an empty string**.

Here is code demo:

```
jshell> Matcher m = Pattern.compile("{3}").matcher("A {3} here");
m ==> java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern={3} region=0,10 lastmatch=]

jshell> while (m.find()) { System.out.println( "<" + m.group() + "> | " + m.start() + " | " + m.end()); }

<> | 0 | 0
<> | 1 | 1
<> | 2 | 2
<> | 3 | 3
<> | 4 | 4
<> | 5 | 5
<> | 6 | 6
<> | 7 | 7
<> | 8 | 8
<> | 9 | 9
<> | 10 | 10
```

As per [`Pattern Javadoc`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) it defines greedy quantifier:

> `X{n}`    `X`, exactly `n` times

Here `X` is just an empty string so what it means is that an empty string exactly 3 times which is still an empty string only.